# Will my laptop still work if I remove the camera module?

Tags: laptop, webcam

I want to remove the camera from my old laptop and use it for something else, if I do that will the laptop be fine ? Or will it cause some hardwere issues and it won't work anymore ?

Comment: Depends on too many factors to count.

Comment: @harrymc So if I just take out the camera but cutting the wires, it will probably brake it ..

Comment: Laptop cameras are built in, so removing it will almost surely damage it. After-market Cameras with USB connection are very inexpensive. Just get a camera to suit your needs

Comment: Most likely you will break it, unless you are a technician and know perfectly well this laptop (but if you were you wouldn't be asking here).

Comment: In addition, the camera may not be usable on another computer.

Comment: Not sure why this was closed as opinion based.  It has a clear and definitive answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most built in cameras in laptops are simply USB devices.  This allows laptop manufacturers to source cameras from different vendors as prices change, or if the vendor stops making it.

This means you should be able to simply unplug the camera with no adverse affects to your computer.  This also means you should be able to attach it to another USB host controller and use it, assuming the device is recognized.  Most use a generic driver, so they often will work without issue.

If for some reason it isnt a USB device, I would find it hard to believe removing it would cause an issue.  But if it did, simply reattach it.

Comment: I do not agree with the above. Laptop cameras I see are built into the screen bezel and the bezel / display would have to be dis-assembled to get at the camera. More harm than good would result.

Comment: @John You can disagree all you want.  However that doesnt change the facts.  These devices are removable and replaceable.

Comment: Not on any variety of laptops I have seen. Please edit your post and post a picture of a laptop with a removable camera.  Of course cameras can be replaced in order to repair them but that means a lot of disassembly

Comment: @John Lol!  Feel free to use Google as none of this is new.

Comment: I just opened the laptop and unplugged the camera from it's little connector, everything still works, but I kind of need some of the cable too, I assume that even if I cut it, it won't be a problem. I want to connected to a USB cable.